# KML. Google Map V3. Performance. Labels

Tags: google-maps, kml

i can not find answers on my questions in google, i hope for sharing your experience with me.

I am going to use KML in Google Maps. My elements are polygons, icons. Also i have to write and rotate text inside polygons, i know KML does not support this element type i am going to use something like [ELabel extension](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/elabel.htm) with some modifications.

My questions are:

1) What is faster either use nature Google KML Processor + ELabel or the third-party [KML Processor](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) + Elabel ?

2) Are there alternative ways to get my task ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ELabel is for Maps API V2. Since that's been deprecated, you should use Maps API V3 instead. If you do use Maps API V3, you can capture the mouse click on the KML layer and create your own infowindow, showing it the way you want. Here's more information:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#KMLLayers

Comment: Thanks, i must write text inside polygon. InfoWindows is not that i really need.